# Represent encoding used for a text file

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding

How is the encoding for a simple text file stored?

In an email there's a header

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
```

In html we have a meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

That leaves me the question of how a text editor knows what encoding is used, since we don't explicitly set this in a text file as we do with an html file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a standard complex format, like `.docx` or `.pdf` the encoding is likely to be stored there as some sort of a property.

If it's a simple file, like `.txt`, `.csv` the encoding will not be stored anywhere. A text editor will use heuristics to determine which encoding was used to save the file, but it will only be a guess.

Read more:

- [How to detect the encoding of a file?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file)
- [Heuristic to detect encoding](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=heuristic+to+detect+encoding)

Comment: That's interesting, thanks for the explanation and the links.